# How to bin into the degree in a logarithm scale in a Pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, dataframe, calculated-columns, logarithm, binning

I want to bin as efficiently as possible numbers of a Pandas dataframe column into the degree in a logarithm scale.
By logarithm scale, I mean the way to display numbers over a `power(unit, degree)` range:

| Degree | Power(10, degree) | Power(2, degree) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| -2 | 0.001 | 0.25 |
| -1 | 0.1 | 0.5 |
| 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 10 | 2 |
| 2 | 100 | 4 |

Giving the following toy dataset:

```
df = pandas.DataFrame(data={'number' : [0.478, 897.12, 12.56, 8.89, 1578.45, 0.089, 0.007]})
```

I would like to easily calculate the column *log_10_class*:

| number | log_10_class |
| --- | --- |
| 0.478 | 0 |
| 897.12 | 3 |
| 12.56 | 2 |
| 8.89 | 1 |
| 1578.45 | 4 |
| 0.089 | -1 |
| 0.007 | -2 |

Answer (score 0):

```
def bin_log_scale(
    numb_sr: pandas.core.series.Series,
    log_unit : float,
    min_pow_deg: int,
    max_pow_deg: int
):
    """ Bin a float into a degree of a logarithm scale
    Parameters:
        - numb_sr : Pandas serie of number
        - log_unit : logarithm scale unit
        - min_pow_deg : minimal power degree
        - max_pow_deg : maximal power degree
    Returns:
        - a Pandas serie identifying the degree of the logarithm scale
    """
    # Initialisation with the minimum class
    class_sr = pandas.Series(
        data = min_pow_deg,
        index = numb_sr.index
    )
    # Incrementation of the class each time numbers are higher its lower bound 
    for pow_deg in range(min_pow_deg, max_pow_deg):
        class_sr = class_sr + 1*(numb_sr > pow(log_unit, pow_deg))
        
    return class_sr

#  Create the new column with the log-10 scale class
df['log_10_class']=bin_log_scale(
    numb_sr = df['number'],
    log_unit = 10,
    min_pow_deg = -2,
    max_pow_deg = 4
)
df
```